# Passing coroutine parameters by Rvalue reference

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++-winrt, c++-coroutine

From the C++/WinRT [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency)

```cpp
IASyncAction DoWorkAsync(Param const& value) {
    auto safe_value = value;
    // It's ok to access both safe_value and value here.
    co_await DoOtherWorkAsync();
    // It's ok to access only safe_value here (not value).
}
```

This make sense, just a dangling reference. <strike>However, in the past I've found I've had to.</strike>

> ```
> IASyncAction DoWorkAsync(Param value) {
>     auto safe_value = value;
>     // It's ok to access both value here.
>     co_await DoOtherWorkAsync();
>     // It's ok to access only safe_value here (not value).
>  }
> ```

and just now I've spent too much time debugging to find out it was this problem yet again.

```cpp
IASyncAction DoWorkAsync(Param&& value) {
    co_await DoOtherWorkAsync(); // value deconstructor called
    some_function(std::move(value)); // BOOM
}
```

Is this suppose to happen? The docs don't mention it. What's going on?

Comment: This is not coroutine specific. What's going in is that you've taken a reference parameter, control has passed to some code that destroyed the underlying object, and now you have a problem. This can happen with or without coroutines. I am also confused about your second example: a by-value parameter lives inside the coroutine state and shouldn't become invalid, unless it contains references/pointers to other objects that become invalid. There should be no need to make a `safe_value` and using one probably wouldn't help if there was a problem.

Comment: @HTNW Yeh, the second example probably never happened. what actually happen is cppwinrt generates a function which goes off the page, I refactor it into a coroutine. BOOM, I don't realize the parameter is passed by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rvalue references are *references*; they don't have any special power governing lifetimes outside of the fact that they can manifest temporaries from prvalues like a `const&`.

As for value parameters, that depends entirely on what the object is *doing*. Coroutines already store a copy of the parameter internally. You copying it again at the start of the coroutine is meaningful only to the extent that this copy preserves some resource that the *original* copy would not. That depends on the type of the parameter.

Comment: I guess I use to use Rvalue references as lvalues that "had to be moved in". Hmmm... Could you tell me what's happening with the stack frame with Rvalue references?

Comment: @TomHuntington: The same thing that's happening with the stack frame with lvalue references. `std::move` is just a cast; the actual move only happens when you invoke a move constructor or assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the second example never happened, its just the first example. You see cppwinrt generates code like this

```cpp
void winrt::MyApplication::implementation::UserControl::ToggleButton_Unchecked(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
```

and I don't bother making it fit onto one line.

And I guess I thought the parameters where by value when they where by reference, woops.

## Corountines are just asking for dangling references!

Comment: _and I don't bother making it fit onto one line_, thanks, man :D

Comment: The code generated by cppwinrt.exe is perfectly valid. Had you declared `ToggleButton_Unchecked` as returning one of the `IAsyncXyz` types, cppwinrt.exe would have generated code that takes arguments by value instead. Which we have—4 decades later—identified as the only subset of C++ types with sane semantics.

Comment: Woops, I meant I invalidly refactored `cppwinrt`'s generated code into a coroutine.